# What does "buggy" mean in "a hot, buggy August morning"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives

While reading a [short story](http://www.decompmagazine.com/badliving.htm), I came across a use of the word "buggy" that I'm not familiar with:

> It’s a hot, buggy August morning, too early for lunch, so we find a deserted picnic table without much problem.

I found two definitions of buggy ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/buggy)):

1. infested with bugs.
2. *Slang.* crazy; insane; peculiar.

To me, neither makes sense in this context. Why would anyone call a morning "buggy"? So I though maybe I'm missing something here. So my questions are:

1. If it means one of the above, is it in a good sense or a bad sense. Does the sounds of bugs make it a lively morning or an annoying one, etc. Is it a lovely morning or a gloomy one?
2. If it means/implies something else, how would you describe it?

Comment: I don't see why it couldn't be a morning infested with bugs. As in, more insects around than usual. That would tend to deter other picnicers but why the narrator doesn't care, I can't say.

Comment: Well, I thought it's an odd thing to say about a morning. A strange way to describe it. That's why I wasn't entirely sure. I'm not a native English speaker so I cannot always trust my own ears :)

Comment: There is no mood given. The fact it is before lunch and there are lots of bugs in the air made it very easy to find a picnic table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning *infested with bugs* applies. The whole phrase indicates that there were many bugs that morning (typical for many areas of the US in August).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. So, in terms of moods, is it a good, bad or a neutral one? What would you think?

Comment: Round here, it means the mosquitoes are out. That's unpleasant.

Comment: *Buggy* is appealing only to birds, bats and entomologists. It was unpleasant and that is why the picnic tables were deserted.

Comment: @canpolat see my answer for details on the experience

Answer (score 1):

This kind of 'buggy' generally holds a few implications, which are implicate with semi-tropical and temperate regions, common to the US Southeast:

1. the air is warm-hot
2. the humidity is high
3. the air is not circulating (little breeze)
4. **these conditions breed insect larvae**
5. the most displeasant insects are flying insects
6. many small gnat-like insects swarm in clouds, which are awful to walk into accidentally
7. mosquitos are also very common
8. most people's houses were not sealed well, and thus these insects could come inside (no rest)
9. Because of the climate, people sweat more (which is uncomfortable)
10. many insects are drawn to human sweat because of the salts / etc.

Comment: Did you mean "semi-tropical" instead of "semi-topic"?